# Codeigniter, Ion-auth: mail user password

Tags: codeigniter, email, passwords, auto-generate, ion-auth

I use Wordpress as a CMS, and it has a nice option whereby, when an admin creates a user, Wordpress generates a password and emails it to the user, who can then login and change it to something more memorable. Can such a feature be implemented in the Codeigniter Ion-auth library?

I'm using Ion-auth in an application I'm developing, and the client has already asked for the feature. In the application, only admins can add users - there's no self-registration.

If not, no big, I'll just tell the client that she'll have to create users with passwords of her own choice, or I'll point her towards a random password generator.

Comment: ion auth has this features already build in you can send activation code when user can click and activate his/her account just copy create_user method from auth controller to your application just made email activation true in config file

Comment: I've set activation in the ion-auth config, but it just sends out an email with an activation link. I would like ion-auth to auto-generate passwords and send them out with the activation email. I've read the ion-auth fine manual but have seen no mention of this, and it may not be possible.

Comment: that you have to do at your own when admin create any username just send plain password to user

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks. So I'll need to capture the password as plain text from the POST array as soon as the user is registered, as otherwise the pass is stored in the database with SHA encryption.

Comment: yes you have to do same thing